# Behavior of C# with Nullables

Tags: c#, nullable

In C#
`int? a1 = 0;
int? a2 = 100;
a1 = a1 | default(int?);
a2 = a2 | default(int?);`

Both a1 and a2 turns out to be null. Would be great if someone would explain its working.

### Update

The reason I brought up this insane example was the behavior when int? is replaced by bool? and the binding process.

`bool? a1 = null;
bool? a2 = true;
a1 = a1 | default(bool?);
a2 = a2 | default(bool?);`

This piece of code does not give a warning saying the result of the expression is always null. The inferred reason is **'I_dont_know'|int = 'I_dont_know'** where as **'I_dont_know' | true = true**

Correct me If I'm wrong

Comment: What are you trying to do? What would you expect the result to be? Do you know what the value of `default(int?)` is? Do you know what `|` means?

Comment: As Lippert puts it "the OR of a number and 'I don't know' is 'I don't know'".

Comment: the default value of a nullable type (regardless of the underlying type) is always null.

Comment: bsoundra: you need to be more specific in your update. guidelines: (a) provide original code, (b) provide what you see as behaviour, (c) what you expect, or what puzzles you. In the int? case it was clear, but your update is muddying the waters a bit, so to speak. One reason for my confusion is that I can't construct a working piece of code that the compiler will accept with bool?. So I would advise you provide the details and one of us will help you out :-)

Comment: @PrashantGupta I have made some edits. Please see if it adds more clarity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because of the following reasons..

```
1] default(int?) will always return 'null'
2] null | <anything> returns 'null'
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Btw, visual studio should complain that your expressions always resolve to null. (a warning).

Comment: Like mentioned in the update, this behavior changes when int is replaced by bool and null | true will be true attributed by the change of the role of the operator. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

First note that this isn't different from writing:

```
int? a1 = 0   | default(int?);
int? a2 = 100 | default(int?);
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
int? a1 = 0   | null;
int? a2 = 100 | null;
```

since **[the default keyword used on a reference type yields `null`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**. And since

```
<any integer> | null
```

always evaluates to `null`, you have:

```
int? a1 = null;
int? a2 = null;
```

which explains why both values are `null`.